# steady state initialization in Modelica

Tags: initialization, modelica

For example, I have a multibody vehicle model with an **initial** height of, say 0.1 meter (all wheel vertical loads = 0), as the sim runs, the vehicle will drop onto the ground, after 10 seconds, it reaches its steady state.

I wonder if it is possible to initialize the model exactly at the steady state? I read something about the homotopy command, but I was not even sure if it is something that I was looking for due to lack of examples, so I am not able to implement it to my model. I wonder if there are any other solutions to this kind of initialization problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or if possible, is there a way to run the transient model first and wait until steady state, then use the results to reinitialize the model?

Comment: If you are using Dymola, you should read this page: http://www.claytex.com/how-to-restart-a-simulation/

Comment: If you get everything to work to your satisfaction, you could give a short self-answer and accept it.

Comment: The link of matth is outdated. Meanwhile you have to use this one: https://www.claytex.com/blog/how-to-restart-a-simulation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for Matths comments.

1. The web page matth has provided is very helpful, and if anyone wants to start your simulation from steady state, you should take a look.
2. I found some details on simulation continuation and more commands from User Manual 1, "Simulator API" section.

Here's one more additional question based on this one,

Is there an equivalent C function in the Dymola/source folder of ImportInitial(), Or ImportInitialResult()? Thanks.