# How to start simulation at specified time for different models in DYMOLA?

Tags: modeling, modelica, dymola

I have made 3 models in dymola and want to rum them sequentially (one after the other) in such a way that the output of one should pass on as an input to the next. My models calculate temperature and the final temperature of one model should be the initial temperature of the next model. 
can you please suggest a way for this? Could stategraph be used for this purpose and how?

Comment: See if this could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335048/steady-state-initialization-in-modelica

Comment: You'll need to do some kind of scripting here.  Modelica doesn't have any built-in capabilities to do this.  It will require scripting at the tool level (see the link that HYu mentions as well for specific help with Dymola).

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is quite old, it is definitely a problem others might face also, so here answer (a little late...).

In Dymola the described problem can be solved very easily with the function `DymolaCommands.SimulatorAPI.simulateExtendedModel`. It allows setting the start and stop-time for a simulation, initialize states and read the final values of variables.

Here is an example how an modelica function could look like which uses `simulateExtendedModel` to carry over the simulation result from `Model1` to `Model2`. It is assumed that a temperature sensor is used in both models to measure the temperature of interest and the start temperature of a heat capacitor is initialized:

```
function Script
protected 
  Modelica.SIunits.Temperature T[1] "Stores the final temperature at simulation end";
  Boolean ok "Indicates if simulation completed without error";
  String models[:] = {"MyLib.Model1", "MyLib.Model2"} "Full class paths for models to simulate";
algorithm 
   // Simulation 1 with model 1 from 0s to 1s  
  (ok, T) :=DymolaCommands.SimulatorAPI.simulateExtendedModel(
    models[1],
    startTime=0,
    stopTime=1,
    finalNames={"temperatureSensor.T"},
    resultFile=models[1]);

   // Simulation 2 with model 2 from 1s to 2s    
  (ok, T) :=DymolaCommands.SimulatorAPI.simulateExtendedModel(
    models[2],
    startTime=1,
    stopTime=2,
    initialNames={"heatCapacitor.T"},
    initialValues={T[1]},
    finalNames={"temperatureSensor.T"},
    resultFile=models[2]);

  // Plot temperature output of all models
  for m in models loop
    createPlot(
      id=1,
      heading="temperatureSensor.T",
      y={"temperatureSensor.T"},
      legends={m},
      filename=m+".mat",
      erase=m==models[1],
      grid=true,
      position={0, 0, 700, 400});
  end for;
end Script;
```

Note the second return value of `simulateExtendedModel` is a vector (as one could access more than one final values with `finalNames`), hence the variable `T` is vectorized.